# ¿Cual es la alternativa de fragment o el nuevo componente en android?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Por que fragment no funciona, me dice fragment deprecated 
cuando instancio me sale error:

```
 Fragment fra = new usersFragment();
```

Y cuando quiero reemplazar tambien me sale error, se marca de rojo
,no funciona para nada

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fra)
                    .commit();
```

Si fragment no funciona,cual es al alternativa o el nuevo componente el que tengo que usar?

Comment: Pon los errores completos y el código completo de la App aqui no se puede ver el fragmento usersFragment ni su completa implementación

Comment: Cual es el package del fragment que estas importando?

Comment: Bueno ya lo solucione el error se debia a una mala importacion. por defecto al crear un Fragment se importa import android.app.Fragment;  y esto es en desuso, lo he importado import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment; en el fragment y en la activity que lo llama.

Comment: Por favor no coloques solucionado a tu pregunta, en su lugar publica la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno ya lo solucione el error se debia a una mala importacion. Al crear un Fragment por defecto se importa import android.app.Fragment; y esto esta en desuso, lo he importado import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment; en el fragment y en la activity que lo llama.y desde luego todo funciona normal. 
He cambiado

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

a

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
```

en el activity que lo contiene y en el fragmento